# PHP Session Variables -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, session

I need some help with session variables. I've used them before, but it's been a while, and evidently I'm missing something. I coded the following example demonstrating how I think session variables should work but I'm missing something. A value is submitted from page1.php, value is passed to page2.php. The session variable is populated, displays correctly on page2.php but, once I go back to page1.php, the variable is empty. Where's my screw up?
    Thank you!

```
/* page1.php code ============================== */
    <?php session_start(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Page 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method='post' id='pf' action='page2.php'>
            <input type='text' id='box_inp' size='1' name='pBox'/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form><br/><br/>

        <?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
/* page1.php end ============================== */


/* page2.php code ============================== */
    <?php
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["x_test"] = $_POST["pBox"];
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>

        <br/><br/>

        <a href="page1.php">Back</a>
    </body>
    </html>
/* page2.php end ============================== */
```

Comment: Do you actually have those comment lines in your code?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: and do format your question so that it's in seperate sections. your code is hard to read and follow.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I tested it and it works the way you are expecting it to.

Comment: Considering the whole code as what you've posted, It's working fine!

Comment: You sure you aren't loading the previous page from cache? (*clicking the browsers "back" button instead of the link?*)

Comment: @Darren *Hm...*, even still, it should work. Despite my "not" testing this, I've tested something similar this morning and it worked just fine. OP's leaving something out here. if running from local machine and sessions cache has something to do with it; who knows. You may have a point though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's always the weird questions that are the most intriguing isn't it! ;-P On that note, I agree. OP is leaving something out here, maybe a process they're doing in between that may cause the session not to "stick".

Comment: @Darren what with the spaces before their opening `<?php` tags; they're probably outputting before header, and is failing silently because of it. I instructed the OP to add error reporting, but no word from them. The ball is in their court now ;-) we just need to have it shot back.

Answer (score 0):

Ok your code works fine. It looks like your problem is coming from your confirguration. Check your session configuration in your php.ini.
Here is the manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

and here is a full standard configuration where your session config should work :

```
session.save_handler = files

session.use_only_cookies = 1

session.name = PHPSESSID

session.auto_start = 0

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

session.cookie_path = /

session.cookie_domain =

session.cookie_httponly =

session.serialize_handler = php

session.gc_probability = 1

session.bug_compat_42 = On

session.bug_compat_warn = On

session.referer_check =

session.cache_limiter = nocache

session.cache_expire = 180
```